# How to improve regex for removing source map URLs in js files to avoid catastrophic backtracking

Tags: php, regex, pcre

This regex is used to remove source mapping URLs from an aggregated js file.

```
// Remove JS source and source mapping urls or these may cause 404 errors.
$contents = preg_replace('/\/\/(#|@)\s(sourceURL|sourceMappingURL)=\s*(\S*?)\s*$/m', '', $contents);
```

It fails with `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR` = Catastrophic backtracking when the source map url is a large `//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,...` base64 encoded string I have in some riotjs app file.

See https://regex101.com/r/dB6dL1/1 where I tested this with just the failing snippet from the larger file in question. (Attention this takes quite a while until the processing is finished and the error shows up.

I tried to follow the recommendation for those problems and to use the regex debugger on regex101.com - but even after minutes I get no result from the debugger. Seems to much data / iterations.

Also, I read several times through http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html explanation how to fix that. But I am kind of lost here and reaching the limit of my regex knowhow. Can someone tell me which of the suggested improvements on the catastrophic article is the right one in this case and how to improve the regex above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually your lazy quantifier `\S+?` that is biggest culprit causing **catastrophic backtracking**.

You can use this refactored regex to fix the issue:

```
$re = '~//[#@]\s(source(?:Mapping)?URL)=\s*(\S+)~';
```

There is no need to use `m` modifier either.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB6dL1/2)